# Filter function failing to display results

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following function which I wrote to filter data based of user input.

## controller

```
var app = angular.module("viewJSON",[]);


app.controller("viewCtrl",function Hello($scope, $http) {
       $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './data.json'
        }).then(function (response){
            $scope.products = response.data;
        },function (error){
            console.log("error");
        });

        var data=[];
        $scope.filterData = function ($scope) {
        if ($scope.names.length != 0 && $scope.brands.length != 0){
            data.push(products.name.includes($scope.names) && products.brand.includes($scope.brands));
        }else if($scope.names.length == 0 && $scope.brands.length != 0){
            data.push(products.brand.includes($scope.brands));
        }else if($scope.names.length != 0 && $scope.brands.length == 0){
            data.push(products.name.includes($scope.names));
            }
        return data;
        }
    });
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="viewJSON">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home-page.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="home-page.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="viewCtrl">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="search" ng-innit="x=0">
            <b>Product Name:</b> <input type="text" ng-model="names" class="searchTerm" ng-keydown="x = x+1"><br>
            <b>Product Brand:</b> <input type="text" ng-model="brands" class="searchTerm" ng-keydown="x = x+1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="resultContent" ng-if="x > 0">

            <tr>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Retailer</th>
                <th>Image</th>
            </tr>

            <tr id="rows" ng-repeat="item in filterData">
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.brand }}</td>
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.price }}</td>
                <td class="otherCol">{{ item.retailer }}</td>
                <td class="imageCol"><img ng-src="{{ item.image_url}}"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have played about with this for a while, and to my knowledge the function creates an array based of the users input this array is then displayed using ng-repeat. I have tried using filterBy: filterData, although this gives me the error filter not array which confuses me as the output from filterData is an array. I have a feeling that ng-model is not correctly binding with the values 'names' and 'brands' in the function. A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide data.json file?

Comment: JSON file is formatted as follows: {"product0": {"name": "Junior Girls Rainbow Birds Backpack", "brand": "GUCCI", "price": "\u00a3645.00 ", "gender": "kids: girls", "master_cat": "accessories", "sub_cat": "other", "retailer": "Flannels", "image_url": "https://images.flannels.com/images/products/71007099_5pl.jpg"}

Comment: Theres no problem with parsing the data to a js object as I've had it working before using ng-repeat in a less efficient manner

Comment: data.push(products.name.includes($scope.names)  - you shouldn't using $scope.products.name...? I cannot see products.name variable

Comment: Ive changed all references for products to $scope.products but its still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing any results is your filterData, as filterData is a function and therefore you have to use the following syntax to use it.

```
ng-repeat="item in filterData()"
```

notice the parentheses at the end. Also keep in mind that using a function in ng-repeat is not a good practice as it is called on every DOM update and adds alot of unnecessary work. I would strongly recommend that you put the filtered data inside an array and use that array in your ng-repeat.